# Problema com javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou com um problema no meu código em javascript:

```
function() {
            var largura = document.getElementById('fundo').width;
            console.log("Largura da imagem:" + largura);
            try{
            new Cropper.Img(
                'fundo',
                {
                    onEndCrop: onEndCrop,
                    displayOnInit: true,
                    onloadCoords: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: largura, y2: largura },
                    ratioDim: { x: largura, y: largura }
                }
            );
            }catch(e){
                console.log('ERRO');
            }
        }
```

Essa função é responsável por mandar o tamanho de uma imagem para outro script, que mostrará em cima da imagem um quadrado para fazer corte. O meu problema é que não tá entrando no *new Cropper.Img*. O erro que o navegador apresenta: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Img' of undefined*. Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito agradecido, esse código faz parte de um trabalho da faculdade.

Comment: Qual componente vc está usando (Cropper) e a página da documentação dele?

Comment: http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/ Nesse link vc pode baixar o arquivo, é o cropper.js

Comment: É só baixar o zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo o que eu vi, para usar o Cropper é necessario adiciona os seguintes scripts:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Você pode testar [aqui](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q6BEWHJOD5LhwmVehu6d?p=preview) clicando no botão "cropperIt".